# PHP Search Multiple Database

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to get the results of a search from two different database tables.

I am getting errors and I have no idea why, this is the first time I have used `UNION` ALL so I am not sure if the `syntax` is correct, any help would be appreciated.

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Vectors WHERE
   (`Name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR
   (`Tags` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR
   (`Image` LIKE '%".$query."%')
   UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Photos WHERE
   (`photo_alt` LIKE '%".$query."%')")
```

The initial error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF on line 98

Thanks a lot

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: Do the two tables both have the same amount of columns? With unions  both queries have to return the same amount of columns.

Comment: sorry here is the error,Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF on line 98

Comment: No they dont all have the same amount of columns, I didnt know that, is there another solution? Thanks a lot

Comment: You `T_IF` problem is a php problem. Look at that line in your code and check if it is all correct.
For the query, instead of using `*` write out all your column names. You can create dummy ones for any extra ones that do not match. But perhaps if they do not match you might be using unions wrong. You need to sort one error out at a time though.

Comment: Maybe a quick squint at the rules of using UNION would be useful http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html

Comment: Thanks for the replies...

The semi colon fixed the syntax error and now I get....

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to be able to break things down so you can figure out one problem at a time.

If you are using `xampp` or have a server you can use `phpmyadmin` to check quickly whether a query works.

First you might want to split the query up to test each `select` separately so you know they are both working. After that if you still have a problem it is most likely your `union`.

`Unions` need the columns returned to be equal, so if the first `select` returns 2 columns, the second one must also return 2.

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT `col1a`,`col2a` FROM Vectors WHERE
 (`Name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR
 (`Tags` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR
 (`Image` LIKE '%".$query."%')
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT `col1b`,`col2b` FROM Photos WHERE
 (`photo_alt` LIKE '%".$query."%')")
```

If `Vectors` has 3 columns and `Photos` has 2 columns, but you want to select all 3 columns from `Vectors` within this join than you can create a third column for `Photos`:

```
SELECT `col1b`,`col2b`,null FROM Photos WHERE
(`photo_alt` LIKE '%".$query."%')")
```

---

IMPORTANT: Stop using mysql. It is deprecated, and the way you are using it is especially dangerous and open to `sql injection`. Use `PDO`.

Comment: Great, let us know how it goes, and if this fixed your problem please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Worked perfect, getting results from both tables now. Also I will have a look into PDO, this is all new to me, I have worked strictly front end dev for 3 years, its a whole other ball game. Thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help, def need to be careful with databases if you want to keep a secure system. The php and mysql docs are a great resource. And to get you started - [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-data-manipulation.html). Good Luck!